# checkbox return true (bool) in php

Tags: php, html, boolean

I would like that the checkbox returns 'true' when the user consent.
can you help me please?

```html
 <form action="treat.php" method="POST">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck" name="accept" value='' />
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck">
                I accept all conditions*
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-grid gap-2 col-6 mx-auto">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="">create your account!</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: `value='true'` should work, being aware that it's not going to return a boolean true, anything received from a form is a string.

Comment: In PHP, you can basically just do `$accepted = isset($_POST['accept']);` since only checked checkboxes are sent on form submission.

Answer (score 0):

try to add `value='true'` the boolean value is true or false so you can just fill value with true.